# How do you use select_related for a model method in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I've been using a model method to return a verbose name for a model (Topic). The get_verbose_name method looks something like this:

```
def get_verbose_name(self):
    return self.city.name
```

As you can see, this method retrieves another model using a ForeignKey. This ForeignKey looks something like this:

```
city = models.ForeignKey(City, blank = True, null = True)
```

Unfortunately, this model method, when called in the template using:

```
{{ topic.get_verbose_name }}
```

generates a duplicate query. For performance reasons, is it possible to use select_related in the model method? I know that you can use a *model manager* to use select_related by default, but for a variety of reasons, I would prefer to only use select_related for this **specific** method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to use `select_related` in the model method. By the time method has been called, the `topic` has already been fetched from the database, so it is too late to use `select_related`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Alasdair. So the only alternative is to use a model manager and apply select_related on all objects queries?

Comment: If you are displaying many topics in the same view, then `select_related` is useful as it will roughly halve the number of queries. If you are displaying a single `topic`, then `select_related` has a smaller effect. You might prefer to use `select_related` in the views where it is really useful, rather than using it all the time with a model manager.